# Display Pdf in browser using ejs

Tags: node.js, pdf, ejs

I am working on node mvc with ejs the question i have is i have a response `res.render('pages/search', {prods: products})` and in my search.ejs i have`<iframe src="<%= prods[i].file %>"frameborder="0"></iframe>` with in a for loop those iframes are in amodal popup box this way i send pdf's to the client my question is first time i send those bunch of pdf's it crash the server all the pdf's sent to the browser start downloading & the browser also stuck what can i do to make it works i read something about streaming pdf's but i don't get a way to do that while rendering or in res.render & what is the problem that causes that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `iframe` you should use `embed` tag like this to display PDF

```
<embed src="<%= prods[i].file width="500" height="375" type="application/pdf">
```

Comment: what about mobile devices embed doesn't work

Comment: <object data='some.pdf'>
    <p>Oops! Your browser doesn't support PDFs!</p>
    <p><a href="some.pdf">Download Instead</a></p>
</object>